# getting Regional settings in Javascript from CSOM

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

I am creating a custom data entry app in sharepoint using the CSOM. I need to update the default value of a datetime field, I can get the default value but the datetime is in UTC Format.

I need to convert it to whatever format the sharepoint server uses. I have tried using the SP.Web.RegionalSettings.get_Dateformat() method like so:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
regionalsettings = context.get_web().get_regionalSettings();   //global variable
context.load(regionalsettings);
context.executeQueryAsync(configLoaded, configFailed);
....

function configLoaded(){
var dateformat = regionalsettings.get_dateFormat();
```

but this just returns a 0 value every time

Answer (score 3):

You can simply parse the date using Javascript Date object. If different cultures are being used, you have to get the culture being used and format it accordingly.

```
var date = oListItem.get_item('StartDate');
if(date) {
 date = new Date(date).format('MM/dd/yyyy');
 window.console && console.log(date);
}


//Update
var today = new Date();
oListItem.set_item('StartDate', today);
oListItem.update();
```

Comment: The problem is I dont know what culture is being used? I'm not updating a list, I'm just putting the default value in a textbox.. So I need to know the dateformat to use (I need to get the culture info from Sharepoint)

Comment: Do you have sites in languages other than English? If so, you have to take into account the culture.

Comment: Its all English, but how do I download the culture information from sharepoint?

Comment: There are many ways to get the culture:

a. _spPageContextInfo.currentCultureName 
b. _spPageContextInfo.currentCultureName
c. document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].lang

Answer (score 3):

You could utilize CSOM [TimeZone.UTCToLocalTime method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.timezone.utctolocaltime%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to convert the specified date from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) to local time.

Example

```
(function(){

  var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web = context.get_web();
  var regionalSettings = web.get_regionalSettings();

  var dueDate = new Date();  //set DueDate to [now]
  var localDueDate = regionalSettings.get_timeZone().utcToLocalTime(dueDate);

  context.load(regionalSettings);
  context.executeQueryAsync(
     function() {

         console.log(localDueDate.get_value());
         //
     },
     function(sender,args){
         console.log(args.get_message());
     }
  );

})();
```