# Inside my CSOM code how to convert UTC date time into date time as per the regional settings for the site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I have the following code to get the Created date time for a list item:-

```
((DateTime)item.Created).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " )"
```

now the date time i will get will be in UTC time zone, while our site collection regional setting uses this time zone:-

[image]

so if i have a time inside my SharePoint list view = `25/07/2020 11:05`  i will get it as `25/07/2020 07:05`.. any advice?

Comment: Check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94353/getting-regional-settings-in-javascript-from-csom). let me know if it helps you.

Comment: @GaneshSanap i already read this article but it uses `get_regionalSettings()` inside javascript while i am working on CSOM code which does not have such as method

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
 public static void ConvertUtcToSPRegionalSetting()

        {
           
            string sitrUrl = "http://abc.sharePoint.com/sites/AZV";

            using (var context = new ClientContext(sitrUrl))
            {

                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.TimeZone sharePointTimeZone = context.Web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone;

                context.Load(sharePointTimeZone);
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                var fixedTimeZoneName = sharePointTimeZone.Description.Replace("and", "&");
                //var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
                
                var easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
                var TimeZoneID = "";
                foreach (var z in easternZone)
                {
                    if (z.DisplayName == fixedTimeZoneName)
                    {
                        TimeZoneID = z.Id;
                        break;
                    }

                }
                
                var myTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneID);

                              
                //Destination List
                List oList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestAuthor");

                var listItems = oList.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());

                context.Load(listItems,
                items => items.Include(
                item => item["ReportDate"]
                ));

                context.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (ListItem item in listItems)
                {
                    DateTime reportDate = (DateTime)item["ReportDate"];
                    
                    var ConvertedDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(reportDate, myTimeZone);

                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Original Datetime: {0}-{1}, Converted TimeZone DateTime:{2}-{3}", reportDate.ToShortDateString(), reportDate.ToShortTimeString(), ConvertedDateTime.ToShortDateString(), ConvertedDateTime.ToShortTimeString()));
                                                                            
                }


            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found a solution via the build in helper **UTCToLocalTime**.
I wrote a helper method for that.

```
  public async Task<DateTime> ConvertToSharePointTimeAsync(ClientContext clientContext, DateTime utcTime)
    {
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.TimeZone sharePointTimeZone = clientContext.Web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone;

        var convertedTime = sharePointTimeZone.UTCToLocalTime(utcTime);
        await clientContext.ExecuteQueryRetryAsync();

        return convertedTime.Value;
    }
```